# Can Schema.org VideoObject tags be applied to iframes?

Tags: iframe, seo, microdata, schema.org

Can VideoObject tags ([Schema.org](http://schema.org/VideoObject)) be applied to iframes? Their own example and [this one on googlewebmastercentral](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/using-schemaorg-markup-for-videos.html) mentions nothing on videos embedded with iframes.

Should it be added to the iframe itself with meta inside the iframe, or a wrapping div?

```
<iframe itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/CLIP_ID" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0">
    <meta itemprop="duration" content="T1M33S" />
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the VideoObject tags can be applied to an video embed using an iframe. But if it really helps, given the following post, is the question, check out this post: http://www.reelseo.com/embedded-youtube-indexed-google/.

Also, to give an answer to your (and my) question I used the following Google keywords: https://www.google.com/#q=schema.org+videoobject+iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Are you concerned of Google Snippet (Video Schema Markup)? I this is not possible because Meta tag should be found between **head** tag and **iframe** tag is usually embedding another page so this will be not detected through [Google Snippet Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

More information at http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2278710/Embedded-Video-Schema-Markup-A-7-Step-Checklist-for-Great-Results